# How to retrieve the File object from a URL.createObjectURL(file)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, blob

I have a form with fields and an input type multiple file used to allow the user to import photos.
In order to display these photos in a preview, I do this with the URL.createObjectURL (file) object like this:

```
var $inputPhotos = $('#inputPhotos');
$inputPhotos.change(function () {
    var files = this.files;
    if (files && files.length) {
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
           var file = files[i];
           if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
               var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
               overviewPhoto(blobURL);
           }
        }
        $inputPhotos.val('');
    }
});
```

So when sending the form with an ajax request, I want to retrieve the file object from the blobURL?

```
var formData = new FormData();
for(var i = 0; i < overviewPhotos; i++) {
    var file = overviewPhotos[i] ??????;
    //** how to retrieve the file object from the URL blob object?      
    //** already uploaded by URL.createObjectURL(file);
    //** file to blob with createObjectURL 
    //** and the opposite blob to file with ???
    formData.append('files', file);
}
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function (key, input) {
    formData.append(input.name, input.value);
});
```

can someone help me please!

Comment: you can not retrieve the file from an ObjectURL

Comment: thank you so much! Is there another solution ? convert to base 64 for example?

Comment: how about : file = new File([blobURL], "filename"); ??

Comment: if that works, then what's the problem?

Comment: In your case, it would be better just save that `file` variable in a scope accessible to your second script. And `file = new File([blobURL], "filename");` will  just create a text file with the URL encoded in UTF-8 as only content.

Comment: @JaromandaX The problem is that this solution does not work on all browsers! As well as the format of the file changes from (image / ..) to (application / ..) which implies the impossibility to deduce if the file is an image at the server level.

Comment: @Kaiido, I thought of this solution but it will take more code, more test since the user can delete or move these photos after import (after viewing photos), I already have an array variable for URLs photos (blob : url) and if I use another variable array for storing files in its original format, it will manage this variable in the same way of the first variable and at the same time! I think this solution is not right.

Comment: If your user re/move the files on their disk after you did generate a blobURI from these, your blobURIs are broken, they don't point to anywhere anymore. Just make a correct design from the start with a nice API that classifies and manage all your files nicely. Tests will be easy to do, and so will be management. Note that I didn't said to make this variable accessible, but to store it somewhere accessible. You are responsible for your code design, we don't do it in here.

Comment: @Kaiido, Yes I totally agree with you, with this proposal, and I understand that this variable is not accessible, I have a table to store blobs to make it show a slideshow, and it will take another table to store the files, it is a solution, I seek if there is another solution better than that?

Comment: Nope nothing better than a good design. Now if you really wish, I pointed you to Q/As that give some ways to make URL.createObjectURL store these files for us, but honestly you'd better make your ownn API (for instance will be usefull when you'll want to let users add some metadata, change the filenames etc.

Comment: @Kaiido, Here is an excerpt of code from this proposal:
Object.defineProperty(URL, 'createObjectURL', {
get: () => saveAndCreate
});
function saveAndCreate(blob) {
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob); // 1st variable for blobs
dict[url] = blob; // 2nd variable for files
return url;
}

Comment: with pleasure sir, but for my question, I think it will implement your proposal (store the files somewhere)! thank you for your help and do not try to point me to solutions rather fair.